# Infinite sum of falling factorial quotients.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Computing the infinite sum of falling factorial quotients in *Mathematica* I've got the result: 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z_1^\underline{k}}{(-z_2)^\underline{k}}=\frac{\Gamma(z_2)\Gamma(z_1+z_2-1)}{\Gamma(z_2-1)\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}.
$$
How to prove the result? What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for convergence of the series, assuming that both $z_1$ and $z_2$ are not integer? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Simplify the right-hand side using $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Evaluation**

$$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z_1^\underline{k}}{(-z_2)^\underline{k}}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(k-z_1-1)^{\underline{k}}}{(k+z_2-1)^{\underline{k}}}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(k-z_1)}{\Gamma(-z_1)}\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(k+z_2)}\tag2\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(-z_1)\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(k-z_1)\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}{\Gamma(k+z_2)}\tag3\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(-z_1)\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{z_1+z_2-1}}{(1+t)^{k+z_2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag4\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(-z_1)\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{z_1+z_2-2}}{(1+t)^{z_2-1}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag5\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(-z_1)\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}\frac{\Gamma(z_1+z_2-1)\Gamma(-z_1)}{\Gamma(z_2-1)}\tag6\\[3pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{z_2-1}{z_1+z_2-1}}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $z^{\underline{k}}=(-1)^k(k-z-1)^{\underline{k}}$
$(2)$: write the falling factorial using the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$(3)$: algebraic manipulation
$(4)$: apply the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) integral
$(5)$: sum the geometric series
$(6)$: apply the Beta Function integral, which converges for $\Re(z_1)\lt0$ and $\Re(z_1+z_2)\gt1$
$(7)$: $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$

---

**Convergence**

Note that as $k\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{z_1^{\underline{k}}}{(-z_2)^{\underline{k}}}
&=\frac{(k-z_1-1)^{\underline{k}}}{(k+z_2-1)^{\underline{k}}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(k-z_1)}{\Gamma(-z_1)}\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(k+z_2)}\\
&\sim\frac{\Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(-z_1)}k^{-z_1-z_2}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, as long as $z_2$ is not a non-positive integer (so that $(-z_2)^{\underline{k}}$ never vanishes), the series will converge for $\Re(z_1+z_2)\gt1$. By analytic continuation, $(7)$ will hold for $\Re(z_1+z_2)\gt1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice proof.  The final expression (8) can be however valid only with certain restrictions imposed on the real parts of $z_1$ and $z_2$. It seems  that you implicitly used the restrictions in transitions $(4)\rightarrow(5)$ and $(6)\rightarrow(7)$. Could you please clarify this and write down the conditions for the validity of the expression (8) explicitly?

Comment: @user355705: I've explicitly added the range of convergence for $(7)$.

Comment: Thank you. Following your proof I came to the same result. But numerical evidence suggests that the condition $\Re(z_1+z_2)>1$ is both necessary and sufficient for the convergence of the series. Particularly it converges also for $\Re(z_1)>0$.

Comment: @user355705: the proof above works for the ranges I've stated. The sum may converge for other values of $z_1$ and $z_2$, and sum will coincide with $(8)$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: I accept your answer. Please let me know if you find out whether the condition $\Re(z_1+z_2)>1$ is indeed both necessary and sufficient for the convergence of the sum.

Comment: One thing for certain is that if $z_2$ is a non-positive integer, then $(-z_2)^{\underline{k}}$ will be $0$ for large enough $k$, so the sum has a singularity (possibly removable) when $z_2$ is a non-positive integer.

Comment: This is clear. I have edited the question to address this issue.

Comment: I have added a section regarding the convergence of the original series. Actually, the identity in the second section allows me to simplify the presentation in the first section.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$S = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(z_1)_k}{(-z_2)_k},$$
where $(x)_k = x^{\underline{k}}$ is the *falling factorial*.

We will make use of the following [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Properties) for the falling factorial
$$(x)_k = \frac{\Gamma (x + 1)}{\Gamma(x - k + 1)}.$$
So in terms of Gamma functions, the above sum can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
S &= \frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1)}{\Gamma (1 - z_2)} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (1 - z_2 - k)}{\Gamma (z_1 - k + 1)}\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \sin (z_1 \pi)}{\Gamma (1 - z_2) \sin(z_2 \pi)} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (k - z_1)}{\Gamma (k + z_2)} \tag1\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \sin(z_1 \pi)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (1 - z_2) \sin(z_2 \pi)} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (k - z_1) \Gamma (z_1 + z_2)}{\Gamma (k + z_2)}\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \text{B}(k - z_1, z_1 + z_2) \tag2\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \int_0^1 t^{k - z_1 - 1} (1 - t)^{z_1 + z_2 - 1} \, dt \tag3\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \int_0^1 t^{-z_1 - 1} (1 - t)^{z_1 + z_2 - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty t^k \, dt \tag4\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \int_0^1 t^{-z_1 - 1} (1 - t)^{z_1 + z_2 - 1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - t} \, dt \tag5\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \int_0^1 t^{-z_1 - 1} (1 - t)^{z_1 + z_2 - 2} \, dt\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \text{B}(-z_1, z_1 + z_2 - 1) \tag6\\
&= -\frac{\Gamma (z_1 + 1) \Gamma (z_2)}{\Gamma (z_1 + z_2) \Gamma (z_1) \Gamma (1 - z_1)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma (-z_1) \Gamma (z_1 + z_2 - 1)}{\Gamma (z_2 - 1)} \tag7\\
&= \frac{z_2 - 1}{z_1 + z_2 - 1} \tag8
\end{align*}

Thus
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(z_1)_k}{(-z_2)_k} = \frac{z_2 - 1}{z_1 + z_2 - 1},$$
and is the simplified expression your Gamma function term reduces to.

**Explanation**

(1) Using Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma (x) \Gamma (1 - x) = \dfrac{\pi}{\sin (\pi x)}$.

(2) Using the property of the Beta function of $\text{B}(x,y) = \dfrac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (x + y)}$ together with Euler's reflection formula.

(3) Using the integral representation for the Beta function of $\text{B}(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x - 1} (1 - t)^{y - 1} \, dt$.

(4) Interchanging the summation with the integration.

(5) Summing the series which is geometric.

(6) Identifying the integral as corresponding to the Beta function.

(7) As in the first part of (2).

(8) Making use of property for the Gamma function of $\Gamma (z + 1) = z \Gamma (z)$.

**Comment on Convergence**

For convergence in the Beta integral appearing in (2) we require $\text{Re}(z_1 + z_2) > 0$ and $\text{Re}(k - z_1) > 0$ implying $\text{Re}(z_1) < 0$ as $k = 0,1,2,\ldots$.

For convergence in the Beta integral appearing in (6) we require $\text{Re}(z_1 + z_2) > 1$ and $\text{Re}(z_1) < 0$.

So the series converges at least for $\text{Re}(z_1 + z_2) > 1$ and $\text{Re}(z_1) < 0$. As for values outside this range I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice proof. I have however the following problem with understanding the transition from (1) to (2). The integral representation of the Beta function requires that real parts of $1-z_2-k$ and $z_1+z_2$ are positive. Whereas the latter condition seems to be the correct one for the convergence of the series, the former condition obviously cannot be satisfied for sufficiently large $k$. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: The summation in $(3)$ does not converge for any $t\in[0,1]$ which is the interval of integration.

Comment: @user355705 - Yes, you (and robjohn's observation) are absolutely correct. I have corrected my answer by first applying Euler's reflection formula before the Beta function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is through the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

In fact the ratio can be written in terms of Rising Factorials and then as terms of the hypergeometric sum 
$$
{{z_{\,1} ^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( { - z_{\,2} } \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }}
 = {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( { - z_{\,1} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {z_{\,2} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}
 = {{\left( { - z_{\,1} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {z_{\,2} } \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{1 \over {k!}}
$$

The infinite sum is therefore the hypergeometric function computed at the unitary value of its argument
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{z_{\,1} ^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( { - z_{\,2} } \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }}}  = {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   { - z_{\,1} ,1}  \cr 
   {z_{\,2} }  \cr 
 } \;} \right|\;1} \right)
$$
which in virtue of the [Gauss theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_values_at_z_=_1)
 gives
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{z_{\,1} ^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( { - z_{\,2} } \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }}}  = {}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   { - z_{\,1} ,1}  \cr 
   {z_{\,2} }  \cr 
 } \;} \right|\;1} \right) = {{\Gamma (z_{\,2} )\Gamma (z_{\,2}  + z_{\,1}  - 1)} \over {\Gamma (z_{\,2}  + z_{\,1} )\Gamma (z_{\,2}  - 1)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {z_{\,2}  - 1} \right)\Gamma (z_{\,2}  - 1)\Gamma (z_{\,2}  + z_{\,1}  - 1)} \over {\left( {z_{\,2}  + z_{\,1}  - 1} \right)\Gamma (z_{\,2}  + z_{\,1} )\Gamma (z_{\,2}  - 1)}}
 = {{\left( {z_{\,2}  - 1} \right)} \over {\left( {z_{\,2}  + z_{\,1}  - 1} \right)}}\quad \left| {\;1 < {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \left( {z_{\,1} } \right) + {\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \left( {z_{\,2} } \right)} \right. \cr} 
$$
including the range of convergence.