# Identity involving falling factorial

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, factorial, gamma-function

Let $(x)_n$ denote the falling factorial,
$$(x)_n = x(x-1) \dots (x - n + 1).$$

I came across the following identity in trying to solve another problem.
$$\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{(a)_k}{(x)_k} = \frac{a}{x - a + 1}\left( 1 - \frac{(a-1)_m}{(x)_m}\right).$$

This identity allows you to find closed forms for sums such as
$$\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\Gamma(x + k)}{\Gamma(y + k)}$$
or
$$\sum_{k = 0}^c \frac{a \choose k}{b \choose k}.$$

It is similar to a series mentioned here ([Infinite sum of falling factorial quotients.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636308/infinite-sum-of-falling-factorial-quotients) ), except that my sum is finite.

I proved the identity by induction, which isn't too hard, as long as you know what you're looking for. I have a couple of questions, though.

- I tried to find this identity mentioned somewhere, but couldn't find it. Is it well-known, or a special case of a better known identity?
- I found the expression on the right-hand side through trial and error. Is there a more natural derivation of the identity, particularly if you know the left-hand side and are looking for the right-hand side?

For example, after multiplying through by $(x - a + 1)(x)_m$, the identity becomes one of polynomials in $a$ and $x$, hence it would be sufficient to prove it for sufficiently large integers $a$ and $x$. Perhaps there is a combinatorial explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrals and Series, Prudnikov, et. al. has in its Finite Sum section, as entry 4.2.8.1

$$ \sum_{k=m}^n \frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}  = \frac{b+1}{b-a+1}\Big(
\frac{\binom{a}{m}}{\binom{b+1}{m}} - \frac{\binom{a}{n +1}}{\binom{b+1}{n+1}} \Big) $$  Thus the OP's sum is known and the above is a generalization.  I have not tried to prove it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this is equivalent to the identity in the OP. The OP follows from it by permanence of polynomial identities, and this follows from the OP by taking the difference of the sums for $m-1$ and for $n$.

Answer (score 2):

We  prove
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}=\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}\left(\frac{\binom{a}{m}}{\binom{b+1}{m}}-\frac{\binom{a}{n+1}}{\binom{b+1}{n+1}}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We  start with the right-hand side of (1) and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{\binom{a}{m}}{\binom{b+1}{m}}-\frac{\binom{a}{n+1}}{\binom{b+1}{n+1}}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=m}^n\left(\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b+1}{k}}-\frac{\binom{a}{k+1}}{\binom{b+1}{k+1}}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{b+1}{b-k+1}}-\frac{\frac{a-k}{k+1}}{\frac{b+1}{k+1}}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{b+1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}\left(\frac{b-k+1}{b+1}-\frac{a-k}{b+1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}\left(b-k+1-(a-k)\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we write  the  expression  as telescoping   sum.
- In (3)  we  factor out $\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k}}$  and   simplify in the following steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a probabilistic proof of the identity in skbmoore's answer, from which the OP's identity follows.

Since the identity can be expressed as a polynomial in the variables $a, b$, it is enough to prove it when $a$ is a positive integer and $b \geq a$ is an integer.

Draw elements at random from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, b + 1\}$, without replacement, and stop when you pick the first element that is not in $\{1, 2, \dots, a\}$. Let $K + 1$ be the number of elements drawn in all.

Then the probability that $m \leq K \leq n$ can be calculated in two ways.

First, it is the probability $\frac{a \choose m}{{b + 1} \choose m}$ of drawing the first $m$ elements in the set $\{1, 2, \dots, a\}$, minus the probability $\frac{a \choose {n+1}}{{b + 1} \choose {n+1}}$ of drawing the first $n+1$ elements in that set.

Second, it is the sum over $k = m, \dots, n,$ of the probability that K = k. Reversing the order of the draw, this is the same as the probability $(b + 1 - a)/(b + 1)$ of picking the first element outside the set $\{1, 2, \dots, a\}$, multiplied by the probability in that case of picking the next $k$ elements in that set, which is $\frac{a \choose k}{b \choose k}$.