# Prove the identity $ \sum\limits_{i=k}^{n} \frac{1}{(i-k)! (a+i)_{n-i}}={\frac {a+n}{ \left( a{+} k \right) (n{-}k)! } }.$

Tags: summation, hypergeometric-function

Playing with hypergeometric series I have got the identity 
$$
\sum_{i=k}^{n} \frac{1}{(i-k)! (a+i)_{n-i}}={\frac {a+n}{ \left( a{+}
k \right) (n{-}k)! } },
$$
here $(x)_s=x(x+1)\cdots (x+s-1),$ $n, k$ are  integers and  $a$ is not integer number.  Is there any direct way to prove it?

**EDIT.**  My attempt for the case $k=0.$ Let   $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{i! (a+i)_{n-i}}. $$ Then by direct calculation one may verify that  $S_n$ satisfy the recurrence equation 
$$
    (a+1)(n+3)  S_{ n+3 }=S_{ n+1} -( n-a ) S_{
  n+2 } ,
$$
with the initial condition 
$$
S_0 =1,S_1={\frac{a+2}{a+1}},S_2 =\frac 1 2{\frac{a+3}{a+1}}.
 $$
By solving it we get that 
$$
S_n= {\frac {a+n}{ a n! } }.
$$

I think that it works for any $k$  but I don't like it.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I add my attempt. But I hope there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=k}^n}&\color{blue}{\frac{(n-k)!}{(i-k)!(a+i)^{\overline{n+i}}}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=k}^n\frac{(n-k)!}{(i-k)!(a+n-1)^{\underline{n-i}}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=k}^n\binom{n-k}{i-k}\binom{a+n-1}{n-i}^{-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}\binom{a+n-1}{n-k-i}^{-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=(a+n)\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}z^{n-k-i}(1-z)^{a-1+k+i}\,dz\tag{5}\\
> &=(a+n)\int_0^1z^{n-k}(1-z)^{a-1+k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}\left(\frac{1-z}{z}\right)^{i}\,dz\tag{6}\\
> &=(a+n)\int_0^1z^{n-k}(1-z)^{a-1+k}\left(1+\frac{1-z}{z}\right)^{n-k}\,dz\tag{7}\\
> &=(a+n)\int_0^1(1-z)^{a-1+k}\,dz\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{a+n}{a+k}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)*  $n^{\overline{k}}=n(n+1)\cdots (n+k-1)$.
- In (2) we use the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* $n^{\underline{k}}=n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$.
- In (3) we use the identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}$.
- In (4) we shift the index $i$ to start with $i=0$.
- In (5) we write the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient using the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we do some rearrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (7) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement)*.

Comment: here is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664857/prove-the-identity-sum-limits-i-0n-1i-a2i-binomni-binoma my new identity

Answer (score 2):

First of all we change the variables
$$ S_n\mapsto(n-k)!S_n\\
i\mapsto i-k\\
n-k\mapsto n\\
a+k\mapsto a
$$
 to bring the expression into a simpler form:
$$
S_n:=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{n-i}}{\binom{a+n-1}{n-i}}=\frac{a+n}{a}.\tag{1}
$$
In what follows we assume $a\not\in\{1-n,2-n,\dots,0\}$.

The equality (1) is obviously valid for $n=0$ and for arbitrary $a$: $S_0=1=\frac{a+0}{a}$. Assuming that it is valid for $n-1$ one obtains that it is valid for $n$ as well:
$$
S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{n-i}}{\binom{a+n-1}{n-i}}=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n}{n-i}}{\binom{a+n-1}{n-i}}=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\frac{n}{n-i}\binom{n-1}{n-i-1}}{\frac{a+n-1}{n-i}\binom{a+n-2}{n-i-1}}\\=1+\frac{n}{a+n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n-1}{n-1-i}}{\binom{a+n-2}{n-1-i}}=
1+\frac{n}{a+n-1}S_{n-1}\\
\stackrel{I.H}{=}1+\frac{n}{a+n-1}\cdot\frac{a+n-1}{a}=\frac{a+n}{a}.
$$

Thus the equality is proved.

Comment: Nice reduction to binomial identity

Comment: In fact your identity is just a special case of [a general one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2632742/355705) (equation (*)) with $z_1=n, z_2=a+n$.